# Evernote Windows Client can not connect to server

Tags: windows-7, evernote

I am using evernote windows client. As the title suggests, it can not sync, giving error message "**Can not connect to the server**". Other applications can connect to the internet. I can use evernote from browsers, so my pc can ping evernote server i guess. I am using windows 7. How to fix this?

Comment: Need more info to answer this: Can you get online? Can all programs access the Internet, or just some? Is your firewall blocking Evernote? Your router? Can you ping? Is name resolution working? What is the error, exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Although my first thought was that your firewall might be blocking Evernote, I remembered a similar problem I had about six months ago.  The guru at Evernote had me run my Anti-Virus program and sure enough it found a bad-guy.  Once that was exterminated Evernote connected as soon as I hit clicked the Synch button.  Don't ask me why this would cause a "cannot connect" but it worked for me.  Give it try and let us know how it comes out.
Slim

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. revoCleaner didn't help, reinstallation too.

Here is the working solution:

1. Close IE and Evernote. You can close also other programms running.
2. Start IE (eve if it is not connecting to Internet), go to menu ->extra ->internet options -> advanced (I'm using the German version, so the tabs could differ)
3. reset all options
4. click on the second "reset" below. Wait until the process is finished.
5. press "ok" and restart IE.
6. Enjoy IE and Evernote!

Best, 
Eugene

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the Internet Explorer open and load a webpage in IE to check it is not in offline mode. Now keeping IE open, run evernote. It will work fine. Well atleast for me it worked. So if anyone finds this helpful then good.

Answer (score -2):

I also meet this problem.
And I close firewall,but it doesn't work.
And I change Evrenote from c: to d:,but it doesn't work.

At last, I check my IE setting--> local setting.
I see it use auto config script.
with uncheck use auto config script.

*And It works well!*

Comment: This post really need some more details.